# Image with EXTRA_TEXT sharing not working in Facebook sharing intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I share the my news through Intent chooser

In my sharing option I share image (EXTRA_STREAM) & text (EXTRA_TEXT)

This sharing option working fine in all apps.

My problem:

It not working in facebook app. It only share the image. My text content not showing.

My code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.setType("image/*");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(context, bitmap,id));
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share News"));
```

Thanks for your answer & valuable comments

Comment: i'm to facing the same problem but my intent works with whatsapp,gmail,messages.  but doesn't works with facebook, insatgram,twitter

Comment: @SnehalGongle it working in Twitter for me. Only facebook it not working

Comment: Look i'm sending images so in my intents images are looking in all the situation but text is invisble in facebook and others

Comment: Sorry twitter is working for me Linkedin Isn't

Comment: @SnehalGongle Any other solution???

Comment: @RanjihKumar at present nope i will try and find it after seeing your question i did a testing on my code and found the bugs

Comment: @SnehalGongle Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for an `ACTION_SEND` implementation to honor both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), with emphasis added:

> get*Extra can have **either** a EXTRA_TEXT **or** EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent.

So, Facebook's app is working correctly. Other apps will behave similarly. Some apps will be generous and will support both of those extras on a single `Intent`. You should not assume that any app will do so.

Also, replace `i.setType("image/*")` with the real MIME type, please. *You* are the one supplying the content; *you* are the one who knows what the MIME type is.

Comment: so according to you facebook wont be supporting the both the formats at the same time i.e EXTRA_STREAM and EXTRA_TEXT ????

Comment: @SnehalGongle: I am saying that Facebook will do what Facebook wants to. And I am saying that the results that you describe fit what the documentation describes.

Comment: i agree because i tried sharing image and text from whatsapp to facebook,Instagram and LinkedIn but it didn't work